# How to import CSV data using Logstash for field type completion in Elasticsearch suggester

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

ElasticSearch Index Creation

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/music/' -d '{}'
```

Field Mapping

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/music/_mapping/song' -d '
{
  "properties": {
    "name" : {
      "type" : "string"
    },
    "suggest": {
      "type" : "completion"
    }
  }
}'
```

LogStash config file, musicStash.config

```
input {
    file {
        path => "pathToCsv"
        start_position => beginning
    }
}

filter {  
    csv {
        columns => ["id", "name", "suggest"]
        separator => ","
    }
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "localhost"
        index => "music"
        document_id => "%{id}"
    }
}
```

Now while executing logstash config file, received following exception in elasticsearch console

```
failed to put mappings on indices [[music]], type [logs]
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mapper for [suggest] conflicts with existing mapping in other types:
[mapper [suggest] cannot be changed from type [completion] to [string]]
at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.FieldTypeLookup.checkCompatibility(FieldTypeLookup.java:117)
```

And error received in logstash console,

```
response=>{"index"=>{"_index"=>"music", "_type"=>"logs", "_id"=>"5", "status"=>400, 
"error"=>{"type"=>"illegal_argument_exception", 
"reason"=>"Mapper for [suggest] conflicts with existing mapping in other types:\n[mapper [suggest] cannot be changed from type [completion] to [string]]"}}}, :level=>:warn}
```

So how to achieve elasticsearch auto-complete feature by importing csv file through Logstash.

Comment: Sheel, How would you achieve importing multiple suggester's for a single document as appose to a single suggester per document when using logstash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the following setting in your `elasticsearch` output:

```
document_type => "song"
```

What happens is that logstash is creating a new type called `logs` ([by default](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-document_type)) and since as of ES 2.0 it is forbidden to have two fields with the same name but different types (`string` vs `completion`)  in the same index, it's erroring out.

Just modify your output like this and it will work:

```
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "localhost"
        index => "music"
        document_type => "song"
        document_id => "%{id}"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm the author of [elasticsearch_loader](https://github.com/Moshe/elasticsearch_loader)
If you just want to load CSV data into elasticsearch you can make use of elasticsearch_loader
After installation you will be able to load csv/json/parquet files into elasticsearch by issuing:

```
elasticsearch_loader \
  --index-settings-file mappings.json \
  --index completion \
  --type song \
  --id-field id \
  csv \
  input1.csv input2.csv
```

Comment: How would your solution work if you need to add multiple suggesters for a single document, For example an address document could have Line1, Line2, Line3 and Postcode all as suggester for the single address field.